# division hiding on scroll due to header sticky

Tags: html, css

I have an issue when I click on the home link it should scroll to the `p1` `id` but when it is getting scrolled to the division with `p1` `id` the heading is getting hidden under the header. How to solve it.Here is my  [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3tc7a59e/) which i have tried.
Below is the working snippet for the same

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.red {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: red;
}

.navigation {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: flex;
  background-color: white;
}

.yellow {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation">
  <ul>
    <a href="#p1">
      <li>
        HOME
      </li>
    </a>
    <li>
      ABOUT
    </li>
    <li>
      CONTACT
    </li>

  </ul>
</div>
<div class="red">

</div>
<div id="p1">
  <h1>
    Udayavaniiii

  </h1>
  <p>https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/ - learn the basics while making a blog http://codingforentrepreneurs.com/ - learn the basics https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uu98pqiUJU8&list=PLEsfXFp6DpzTD1BD1aWNxS2Ep06vIkaeW - coding for entrepreneurs videos https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial01/
    - learn the basics while making a polling app https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLXmMXHVSvS-DQfOsQdXkzEZyD0Vei7PKf - learn the basics while building a journaling app shareeditflaghttps://tutorial.djangogirls.org/ - learn the basics while making
    a blog http://codingforentrepreneurs.com/ - learn the basics https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uu98pqiUJU8&list=PLEsfXFp6DpzTD1BD1aWNxS2Ep06vIkaeW - coding for entrepreneurs videos https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial01/ - learn the
    basics while making a polling app https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLXmMXHVSvS-DQfOsQdXkzEZyD0Vei7PKf - learn the basics while building a journaling app shareeditflaghttps://tutorial.djangogirls.org/ - learn the basics while making a blog http://codingforentrepreneurs.com/
    - learn the basics https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uu98pqiUJU8&list=PLEsfXFp6DpzTD1BD1aWNxS2Ep06vIkaeW - coding for entrepreneurs videos https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial01/ - learn the basics while making a polling app https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLXmMXHVSvS-DQfOsQdXkzEZyD0Vei7PKf
    - learn the basics while building a journaling app shareeditflaghttps://tutorial.djangogirls.org/ - learn the basics while making a blog http://codingforentrepreneurs.com/ - learn the basics https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uu98pqiUJU8&list=PLEsfXFp6DpzTD1BD1aWNxS2Ep06vIkaeW
    - coding for entrepreneurs videos https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial01/ - learn the basics while making a polling app https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLXmMXHVSvS-DQfOsQdXkzEZyD0Vei7PKf - learn the basics while building a journaling
    app shareeditflaghttps://tutorial.djangogirls.org/ - learn the basics while making a blog http://codingforentrepreneurs.com/ - learn the basics https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uu98pqiUJU8&list=PLEsfXFp6DpzTD1BD1aWNxS2Ep06vIkaeW - coding for entrepreneurs
    videos https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial01/ - learn the basics while making a polling app https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLXmMXHVSvS-DQfOsQdXkzEZyD0Vei7PKf - learn the basics while building a journaling app shareeditflag
  </p>
</div>
<div class="yellow">

</div>
<div class="red">

</div>
<div class="red">

</div>
```

Comment: Please go read [ask] first of all. Code relevant to your problem belongs directly into your question, in text form and properly formatted, not just dumped on an external site.

Answer (score 0):

Apply `padding-top:54px` to your `<div id="p1">` as your `header` `height` is `54px` .Hope this will fix your problem

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.red {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: red;
}

.navigation {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: flex;
  background-color: white;
}

.yellow {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: yellow;
}

#p1 {
  padding-top: 54px
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation">
  <ul>
    <a href="#p1">
      <li>
        HOME
      </li>
    </a>
    <li>
      ABOUT
    </li>
    <li>
      CONTACT
    </li>

  </ul>
</div>
<div class="red">

</div>
<div id="p1">
  <h1>
    Udayavaniiii

  </h1>
  <p>https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/ - learn the basics while making a blog http://codingforentrepreneurs.com/ - learn the basics https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uu98pqiUJU8&list=PLEsfXFp6DpzTD1BD1aWNxS2Ep06vIkaeW - coding for entrepreneurs videos https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial01/
    - learn the basics while making a polling app https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLXmMXHVSvS-DQfOsQdXkzEZyD0Vei7PKf - learn the basics while building a journaling app shareeditflaghttps://tutorial.djangogirls.org/ - learn the basics while making
    a blog http://codingforentrepreneurs.com/ - learn the basics https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uu98pqiUJU8&list=PLEsfXFp6DpzTD1BD1aWNxS2Ep06vIkaeW - coding for entrepreneurs videos https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial01/ - learn the
    basics while making a polling app https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLXmMXHVSvS-DQfOsQdXkzEZyD0Vei7PKf - learn the basics while building a journaling app shareeditflaghttps://tutorial.djangogirls.org/ - learn the basics while making a blog http://codingforentrepreneurs.com/
    - learn the basics https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uu98pqiUJU8&list=PLEsfXFp6DpzTD1BD1aWNxS2Ep06vIkaeW - coding for entrepreneurs videos https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial01/ - learn the basics while making a polling app https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLXmMXHVSvS-DQfOsQdXkzEZyD0Vei7PKf
    - learn the basics while building a journaling app shareeditflaghttps://tutorial.djangogirls.org/ - learn the basics while making a blog http://codingforentrepreneurs.com/ - learn the basics https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uu98pqiUJU8&list=PLEsfXFp6DpzTD1BD1aWNxS2Ep06vIkaeW
    - coding for entrepreneurs videos https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial01/ - learn the basics while making a polling app https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLXmMXHVSvS-DQfOsQdXkzEZyD0Vei7PKf - learn the basics while building a journaling
    app shareeditflaghttps://tutorial.djangogirls.org/ - learn the basics while making a blog http://codingforentrepreneurs.com/ - learn the basics https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uu98pqiUJU8&list=PLEsfXFp6DpzTD1BD1aWNxS2Ep06vIkaeW - coding for entrepreneurs
    videos https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial01/ - learn the basics while making a polling app https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLXmMXHVSvS-DQfOsQdXkzEZyD0Vei7PKf - learn the basics while building a journaling app shareeditflag
  </p>
</div>
<div class="yellow">

</div>
<div class="red">

</div>
<div class="red">

</div>
```

Comment: I have got the above thing but I don't want space above the division